# glTexCoord2d has no effect

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to draw a simple texture in opengl. I made a simple class Texture:

```
class Texture{
public:
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned char image[256*256*3];
    int level;
    int border;
    int width;
    int height;    

    Texture (int level =0, int border = 0) : level(level), border(border) {
        glGenTextures(1, &id);
        width = 256, height = 256;
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, level, GL_RGB, width, height, border, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &image[0]);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); 


        for (int i= 0; i<width*height*3; i+=3){
            image[i]=1;//i%255;
            image[i+1] =1;// 255-i%255;
            image[i+2] =1;// i%128;
        }
    }

    void useIt(){
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, id );
    }
};
```

It creates an unsigned char array and fill it with some random data. I'm trying to use it this way:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
texture->useIt();
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

glNormal3d(0, 1, 0);
glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0);
glVertex3f(width/-2.f,height/2.f,depth/2.f);
glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0);  
glVertex3f(width/2.f,height/2.f,depth/2.f);
glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0);
glVertex3f(width/2.f,height/2.f,depth/-2.f);
glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0);
glVertex3f(width/-2.f,height/2.f,depth/2.f);
glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0);
glVertex3f(width/2.f,height/2.f,depth/-2.f);
glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0);
glVertex3f(width/-2.f,height/2.f,depth/-2.f);

glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

It draws the plane, but withouht texture (draws with the previously used material). what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possible issues with your code. Brett Hale already told you, that you need to bind a texture object before uploading data to it with glTexImage.

glTexImage creates copy of the data you supply to it (this is different to the glVertex…Pointer functions, which only take a pointer or offset into a buffer object). However you're filling the image array with data *after* you copied it's contents to the texture. Also you may safely delete the image array after copying the data to the texture.

Last but not least: Those operations are found in a constructor. If you have the texture class instance in a scope that's initialized before a OpenGL context has been created, nothing will happen at all, because there's no OpenGL context. So either make sure, the texture object is created only after a OpenGL context is available, or put the texture creation and upload code into a separate method, that you call once a OpenGL context is available.

Comment: Checked all, and changed everything you mentioned: fill the array with random values before i give it to teximage2d, binded it in time, and the object is created when the opengl context is available. Still nothing:(

Comment: @gberes: Then we need to see more of your code. How to you create your OpenGL context, how and where are drawing functions registered or called.

Comment: FFFFFF.... I started the texture constructor with fillin the array, with this: for (int i= 0; i<width*height*3; i+=3){...} But width and height was set after it.

Answer (score 1):

`glBindTexture` is required in the `Texture` constructor, prior to the `glTex*` operations.

You might also require: `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` prior to `glTexImage2D`, since row memory addresses are not on 4-byte boundaries.

**BTW...,** you need to set the `image` data before you 'upload' it via `glTexImage2D`. Right now, you are just setting the texture with uninitialized data. Furthermore, the loop that sets the RGB byte data is just giving you values very close to black, all: `(1, 1, 1)`.

Comment: I put it after glGenTextures, but nthing changed:(